How to control riff and runs effortlessly? (Singing) (I'm bad at breath control)
Soo, I can do riff and runs nicely, cleanly separated but has bad control and very bad breath control (i think), i have tensions all over my body but not too much. Soo, I feel like I'm not prepared for a performance with vocal runs yet...
My diapraghmatic breathing is loud, people can hear it.. I keep running out of breath after I finished singing a whole vocal run and sometimes (but not often) struggle to breathe before singing a whole vocal run...
I haven't tried open throat technique yet, and I will learn it later maybe.. maybe it'll help me that I sometimes accidentally used my throat instead of diapraghm when singing in the middle of a run.. or maybe not? Any tips please?
Any help is greatly appreciated...
Thank you...
